# How can I add a close button or X to within this iframe which when pressed closes it?

Tags: html, jquery, iframe

I'm trying to create an iframe that is optimised to the webpage size and can be closed easily.This is the code I've got so far. At the moment it adjusts to the webpage but I cannot close it once opened. How could I add a close button within the iframe that could then close itself?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="fun.js"></script>
<style><!--
iframe { 
margin-top:0px;
position: absolute;
top:0; left: 0px;
opacity: 1; 
z-index: 1;
}
--></style>
<script>// <![CDATA[
function fun() {
var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
iframe.src = "URL";
document.body.appendChild(iframe);
iframe.width = '100%';
iframe.height = '100%';
iframe.backgroundColor = 'blue';
iframe.opacity = '100%';
}
// ]]></script>
<div id="button">
<b>Do iFrame</b> <br><br> <button id="dis" onclick="fun()">Click here!</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Just to clarify, do u want to close the iframe? Make it visible false?

Comment: I want to close the iframe through the use of close button within the iframe.